# Issue with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have several servers that have different catalytic structure with the same files. I want to redirect all addresses that have at least 1 phrase `".php/"` for example: `http://localhost/kat1/kat2/kat3/index.php/abc` to `http://localhost/kat1/kat2/kat3/index.php`.
and
`http://localhost/kat1/kat2/kat3/kat4/index.php/abc/index.php`
to
`http://localhost/kat1/kat2/kat3/index.php`.

I try that but it does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).php\/(.*)$ index.php
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]

# remaining rules go below
```